# When MSE was MSO, did reputation show in the flair, etc.?

Tags: support, linked-accounts, combined-flair, mso-mse-split

As someone who never participated in meta (any meta) before the split, I'm curious. Currently, my MSE rep is shown in my network flair, in my linked accounts, etc. Before the split, when it was called MSO, did MSO rep show?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before the split, what is now called MSE was called MSO and showed up in your flair, yes.

It helps to know that what was called Meta Stack Overflow was simply renamed and given a new design. After the rename, a new proper child meta was created for Stack Overflow, given old name and a lot of content was migrated.

As such, all that really happened is that the rename carried through to your flair; the icon simply changed.